# Diophantine equation $10^n-a^3-b^3=c^2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, elementary-proofs

Consider the Diophantine equation:

$10^n-a^3-b^3=c^2$, for $a$, $b$, $c$, and $n$ positive.

Has this equation infinitely many solutions?

Comment: I think you really want to provide a motivation for the question and show your own efforts in solving this problem --- to improve the reception here at MO.

Comment: Feels like an olympiad problem.

Comment: Variation now posted as https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355415/has-this-diophantine-equation-infinitely-many-solutions-for-a-b-not-multiple

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it has.

Note that using (the truly genius observation!) $10^n = 8\cdot 10^{n-1}+10^{n-1}+10^{n-1}$; it suffices to choose $n\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, and $n\equiv  1\pmod{2}$. That is, take $n=6\ell+1$, $\ell\in\mathbb{N}$. Then,
$$
10^n=10^{6\ell+1} = (2\cdot 10^{2\ell})^3 + (10^{2\ell})^3 +  (10^{3\ell})^2.
$$
Thus,
$$
(a,b,c,n)=(2\cdot 10^{2\ell},10^{2\ell},10^{3\ell},6\ell+1),\quad \ell\in\mathbb{N}
$$
is a parametric family along which you get infinitely many solutions.

Comment: are there solutions with a, b c >1 and not multiple of 10?